# In custom Android how to override STREAM_RING as the default AudioService responding to volume buttons

Tags: android, rom

Google docs states if an app isn't playing anything, hitting the volume keys adjusts the ringer volume.
see http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html#HardwareVolumeKeys

I'm sure it is possible to change this 'default' behavior something besides STREAM_RING (say STREAM_MUSIC) by creating custom build from source, so that if the user is at, say the Launcher, and presses the volume button the the STREAM_MUSIC volume will change.
(This require is because the device doesn't have a phone so ring volume is a no-op).

I've looked at the Launcher code but it doesn't show (at least not that I can see) that volume buttons are directed/consumed via AudioManager to STREAM_RING.
Also when in 'Settings' the VOLUME buttons change STREAM_RING, which leads me to further believe there is something 'Up the chain' or 'Down the stack in Application Frameworks or in the Android Runtime'.

Is there a 'higher' Activity or system process running that handles the dispatch of VOLUME to the AudioManager with the STREAM_RING as the channel?
Or is there something within AudioManager that could be set so that it processes VOLUME changes to the STREAM_MUSIC (this seems unlikely from the source as it appears to only process the STREAM in the context of an applications preferred STREAM.

The source I'm using is Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.3.

Answer (score 2):

The solution appears to be setting "config_voice_capable" to false.
This value is found in frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml

I used an overlay to set the "config_voice_capable" to false, then built the rom.

After the device boots the volume controls no longer default to the RINGER stream.
I was not able to find documentation on this regarding differences between
tables and phone capable devices, but the solution works.